# TypeScript: error TS2339: Property 'CustomEvent' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to write a custom element in `Aurelia` using `TypeScript` following [THIS](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/08/aurelia-custom-element-using-select2-tutorial/) guide.

However when trying to compile I am getting the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'CustomEvent' does not exist on type 'Window'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'val' does not exist on type 'Event'.

My class is:

```
import {bindable, autoinject, customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2';
import 'select2/css/select2.css!';

@customElement('select2')
@autoinject
export class CustomSelect{
    @bindable name:string;
    @bindable selected: boolean = false;
    @bindable options: any;
    element: Element;
    
    constructor(element: Element){
        this.element = element;
    }
    
    attached() :void {
        $(this.element)
            .find('select')
            .select2()
            .on('change', ev => {
                let changeEvent;
                if(window.CustomEvent){
                    changeEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {
                        detail: {
                            value: ev.val
                        },
                        bubbles: true
                    });
                } else {
                    changeEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
                    changeEvent.initCustomEvent('change', true, true, {value: event.val});
                }
                this.element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
            }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CustomEvent` is defined in [`lib.es6.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L6678)

Configuring the typescript compilation to target ES6 will fix this issue.  You may need to close and re-open your IDE after making this change.

Comment: Great, I just looked at your other answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452623/aurelia-trying-to-load-html-from-select2 which looks like a much better solution. although I have a question about hooking up to the `change` event which I have now asked there.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't seem to work. I updated the `tsconfig.json`, changing `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"`. I'm using Visual Studio Code. I closed it and reopened it and still have no luck. Any other suggestions?