# Are multiple imports of jQuery (and plugins) really necessary?

Tags: aurelia

In view A I need a jQuery plugin so I do this:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import plugin from 'path/of/plugin';
```

In view B I need just JQuery so I do this:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

If I load view A, then view B, then switch back to A, the plugin seems to be lost. Do I need to load jQuery on every view that needs it or should I import it globally from some main point? If so, how should I go about it?

--- UPDATE ---

Turns out the plugin does not get lost, it was a bundling / exporting issue I did not realize I was having.

Still, the aurelia docs do not seem to provide a clear recommendation on how / where / when to import jQuery and assorted plugins. For example, even jQuery itself, other people import it like this:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

and other like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Do both ways amount to the same thing?

Comment: I think you should read the ES6 spec for importing! https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My question is specific to Aurelia and the  "aurelia way" of importing jQuery & plugins. Any ideas?

Comment: what @FabioLuz said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import jQuery, this is enough:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

To import a Jquery Plugin, that depends on what it exports. Usually, plugins do not export anything. So, you just have to import the file:

```
import 'path/of/plugin';
//now you can $('#something').myPluginFunction();
```

To understand more about importing classes, functions, etc, you should read ES6 spec for importing. Just like @Callum Linington said in his comment.

In my opinion, there is no specific rule for Aurelia, neither "Aurelia way" of importing. The importing mechanism is purely Javascript.

Helpful links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time. Having read posts like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452623/aurelia-trying-to-load-html-from-select2/33453677#33453677 I thought that there is still room for clarifying how things should be done.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this: There is an "aurelia way" after all! Have a look [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/app-configuration-and-startup/7).