# How can I use select2 as an Aurelia attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, aurelia

This is not a duplicate of: [aurelia-trying-to-load-html-from-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452623/aurelia-trying-to-load-html-from-select2)

I am trying to add a *select2* dropdown to the Aurelia [Contact Manager](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial) but I am having problems getting it to work.

My `aurelia.json` looks:

```
...
{
  "name": "select2",
  "path": "../node_modules/select2/dist",
  "main": "js/select2",
  "deps": ["jquery"],
  "resources": [
    "css/select2.css"
  ]
}
...
```

And the custom attribute:

```
import {autoinject, customAttribute} from 'aurelia-framework';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2';
import 'select2/css/select2.css!';

@customAttribute('select2')
@autoinject
export class SelectCustomAttribute {
    element: Element;

    constructor(element: Element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached(): void {
        $(this.element)
            .select2({
                placeholder: 'Select!'
            })
            .on('change', e => {
                if(e.originalEvent) { return; }
            });
    }

    detached(): void {
        $(this.element).select2('destroy').off('change');
    }
}
```

Building the application fails with:

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\MyApp\node_modules\select2\dist\css\select2.css.js']

Removing the `import 'select2/css/select2.css!';` makes it compile but then I would have to load the *css* manually wherever I want to use this attribute which defeats the purpose of having the attribute at the first place:

```
<require from="select2/css/select2.css"></require>
<section class="row container">
    <select select2>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
    </select>
</section>
```

Comment: Not too familiar with typescript, but it looks like when it's setting the element in the constructor, `this.element` is a string, and you're trying to set it to an Element. Of course, you probably already know this, and I didn't really help much :)

Comment: It would help to know what setup you are using, but based off the last error you are getting, my guess is that, at a minimum, you need to comment out a line in the typings file for angular-protractor. In my setup it is at typings/globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts line 1839 declare var $: cssSelectorHelper. I needed to comment that out so there wasn't a conflict with the jquery .d.ts file. I also imported jquery as import 'jquery'; in my custom attribute file

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thanks for the tips, that took me further but still unable to load the _css_ file updated the question.

Comment: Are you using the cli? If so, in the aurelia.json file you need to add `          {
            "name": "select2",
            "path": "../node_modules/select2/dist",
            "main": "js/select2.min",
            "resources": [
              "css/select2.min.css"
            ]
          },` as your select2 node and then change your require to this `<require from="select2/css/select2.min.css"></require>`, it should work

Comment: That's what I already have (see the updated question) I don't want to have to write the `<require..>`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I believe what you want isn't possible directly as noted in the issue here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/273. What I did was place the require on my app.ts as talked about in the discussion there.

Comment: I see, I was importing the code from the _JSPM_ version and in there it did indeed work but looks like the _CLI_ uses `RequireJs` which does not support that syntax at the moment. Thanks for the explanation if you submit an answer I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you are reporting, there are a few things you will need to do.
The `index.d.ts` file for angular-protractor is causing a naming conflict with jQuery's `.d.ts` file.

In `typings/globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts` comment out like 1839(`declare var $: cssSelectorHelper`).

Add the following to your `aurelia.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "select2",
  "path": "../node_modules/select2/dist",
  "main": "js/select2.min",
  "resources": [ 
    "css/select2.min.css"
  ]
}
```

There is an [issue filed](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/273) on the aurelia-cli around importing css files. There are a few solutions there as to how to include .css files. The approach I took was to add `<require from="select2/css/select2.min.css"></require>` to my `app.ts` file.